# How to create this image with the current colors and as a mesh?

Tags: graphics, image

I need to create this image bigger with that coloring, and also as a mesh or wire structure,
please help me.
[image]

I tried to connect the dots, but it didn't work and I deleted it

There is some command that scans the image and extracts the points from it.

Comment: Related [link](https://artofproblemsolving.com/wiki/index.php/2013_AMC_10A_Problems/Problem_14)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**Update**

**Mesh**

```
Clear;
all = Tuples[{0, 1, 2}, 3];
erase = Tuples[{0, 2}, 3];
rest = Complement[all, erase];
Graphics3D[{Lighting -> "Accent", EdgeForm[Blue], FaceForm[], 
  Cuboid[#] & /@ rest}, Boxed -> False]
```

[image]

**Solid**

```
Clear;
all = Tuples[{0, 1, 2}, 3];
erase = Tuples[{0, 2}, 3];
rest = Complement[all, erase];
Graphics3D[Cuboid[#] & /@ rest, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

**2D**

BTW,we can also draw the 2D version.

```
Clear;
all = Tuples[{0, 1, 2}, 2];
erase = Tuples[{0, 2}, 2];
rest = Complement[all, erase];
Graphics[{EdgeForm[Blue], FaceForm[Opacity[0.1]], 
  Rectangle[#] & /@ rest}]
```

**Original**

```
Clear;
vertexs = Tuples[{-3, 3}, 3];
ineqs = Norm[{x, y, z} - #, ∞] >= 2 & /@ vertexs
reg = RegionPlot3D[And @@ ineqs, {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3}, {z, -3, 3}, 
  Lighting -> "Accent", PlotPoints -> 80, Mesh -> None, 
  PlotStyle -> Gray, BoundaryStyle -> {Thick, White}, Boxed -> False, 
  Axes -> False]
(*Needs["NDSolve`FEM`"]
reg // DiscretizeGraphics // ToElementMesh
%["Wireframe"]*)
```

[image]

Comment: @cvgmt_The first image was fantastic, the second I do not know how you achieved it but my idea was something else, something like this                                                       https://image.shutterstock.com/image-vector/cube-3d-mesh-wireframe-web-600w-699964732.jpg but without the points, you could make some modifications to the code to make it like the example, thanks for your time.

Comment: @cvgmt_I am very good, in the first code that you wrote something you modified because the edges were rounded not with white lines (you could put the initial code that you said that it was necessary to improve, I did not record it)

Comment: @zeros  you can remove `BoundaryStyle -> {Thick, White}`   just like `vertexs = Tuples[{-3, 3}, 3];
ineqs = Norm[{x, y, z} - #, ∞] >= 2 & /@ vertexs
reg = RegionPlot3D[And @@ ineqs, {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3}, {z, -3, 3}, 
  Lighting -> "Accent", PlotPoints -> 80, Mesh -> None, 
  PlotStyle -> Gray,Boxed -> False, 
  Axes -> False]`

Comment: I made the change in the code you proposed but I got errors,I don't know what I'm doing wrong,I have checked it several times

Comment: `vertexs = Tuples[{-3, 3}, 3];
ineqs = Table[
   Norm[{x, y, z} - pt, ∞] >= 2 , {pt, vertexs}];
reg = RegionPlot3D[And @@ ineqs, {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3}, {z, -3, 3}, 
  Lighting -> "Accent", PlotPoints -> 80, Mesh -> None, 
  PlotStyle -> Gray, BoundaryStyle -> {Thick, White}, Boxed -> False, 
  Axes -> False]`

Comment: @cvgmt_thanks ,now it works for me

Answer (score 7):

```
rp = RegionPlot3D[RegionDifference[Cuboid[], CantorMesh[1, 3]], 
  Lighting -> "Neutral", Boxed -> False, PlotTheme -> "Monochrome", ImageSize -> Large]
```

[image]

```
coords = DeleteCases[_List?(FreeQ[1/3 | 2/3])] @ Tuples[Subdivide[3], 3];

nng = Show[NearestNeighborGraph[coords, VertexSize -> 0, 
    VertexCoordinates -> coords, ImageSize -> Large]] /. 
        Tube[x_, ___] :> {Thick, Black, Line[x]}
```

[image]

```
Show[rp, nng]
```

[image]

Comment: @kglr_you were very good representations I congratulate you

Answer (score 6):

**Based on `ArrayMesh`**

```
ArrayMesh[Normal@SparseArray[Tuples[{1, 3}, 3] -> 0, {3, 3, 3}, 1]] //
   BoundaryDiscretizeRegion // Region`Mesh`MergeCells
```

[image]
**The previous answer**

```
reg=BoundaryDiscretizeGraphics[RegionUnion[Cuboid/@Complement[Tuples[{0,1,2},3],
  Tuples[{0,2},3]]]]//Region`Mesh`MergeCells;

Graphics3D[{{Opacity[0.8],reg},{Red,Tube@@@MeshPrimitives[reg,1]}}]
```

[image]

Related
[2013 AMC 10A Problems/Problem 14](https://artofproblemsolving.com/wiki/index.php/2013_AMC_10A_Problems/Problem_14)

> A solid cube of side length $1$ is removed from each corner of a solid cube of side length $3$. How many edges does the remaining solid have?
> [image]

```
Length[MeshPrimitives[reg, 1]]
```

> 84